# Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219: on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Im getting the errors above. I tried to read on other forums with the same problem but with no luck. My create, store and edit are working. However when updating my form im getting the error above. Can someone help me on this. Thanks

```
{!! Form::model($enrollment['method'=>'POST','route'=>['/enrollment',$enrollment->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject_code" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" name="_method" value="PUT" id="subject_code">
                            <option value="{{ $enrollment->subject_code }}">{{ $enrollment->subject_code }}</option>
                            @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                                <option value="{{ $subject->subject_code }}">{{ $subject->subject_code}}</option>
                            @endforeach 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject_description" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject description</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" name="subject_description" id="subject_description">
                            <option value="{{ $enrollment->subject_description }}">{{ $enrollment->subject_description }}</option>
                            @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                                <option value="{{ $subject->subject_description }}">{{ $subject->subject_description}}</option>
                            @endforeach 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject_code" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" name="subject_code" id="subject_code">
                            <option value="{{ $enrollment->section }}">{{ $enrollment->section}}</option>
                            @foreach($sections as $section)
                                <option value="{{ $section }}">{{ $section }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject_code" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" name="subject_code" id="subject_code">
                            <option value="{{ $enrollment->schedule }}">{{ $enrollment->schedule }}</option>
                            @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                                <option value="{{ $subject->schedule }}">{{ $subject->schedule}}</option>
                            @endforeach 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject_code" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" name="subject_code" id="subject_code">
                            <option value="{{ $enrollment->no_of_units }}">{{ $enrollment->no_of_units }}</option>
                            @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                                <option value="{{ $subject->no_of_units }}">{{ $subject->no_of_units}}</option>
                            @endforeach 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                            &nbsp;Save Changes
                        </button>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                            &nbsp;Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>                                                                              
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here's my EnrollmentController:

```
    public function update(EnrollmentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $enrollment = Enrollment::findOrFail($id);
    $enrollment->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/enrollment');
}
```

routes.php

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::resource('enrollment','EnrollmentController');
```

Comment: Ths usually happens when u have same route for get and post methods.

Comment: @MasterSith then what's the solution for this?

Comment: I know you are using resources and that is fine, but create new route to new function.
like Rouse::POST('update', 'Controller@update'); also use capital latters

Comment: @MasterSith POST is not valid keep in mind. It should be in small letter.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Ian what's stack trace? Sorry Im not familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have a mistake in your HTML. In your very first "subject_code" input, you have the following HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="_method" value="PUT" id="subject_code">
```

You've accidentally named this input as `_method`, which is the reserved input name for Laravel method spoofing. Even though you've assigned the value as "PUT", this is not how selects work, and the value will end up being something else. This is preventing the Laravel method spoofing from working correctly. Since the method spoofing is not working, you're sending a POST request to `enrollment/{id}`, and that route does not allow POST requests.

You need to correct this input so that it is not named "_method":

```
<select class="form-control" name="subject_code" id="subject_code">
```

Additionally, you need to fix your `Form::model()` statement. It needs to take two parameters, where the first is the model, and the second is an array of attributes. In your array of attributes, you need the "method" to be "PUT" (so that the form builder will automatically create the hidden "_method" input), and you need the first element in the "route" array to be the name of the route, not the url. Updates shown below:

```
{!! Form::model($enrollment, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['enrollment.update', $enrollment->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I did not notice that. Thank you for your answer.I think you forgot to place colon on $enrollment?

Comment: {!! Form::model($enrollment,['method'=>'PUT','route'=>['/enrollment',$enrollment->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
shareeditflag
answered 10 mins ago

Comment: {!! Form::model($enrollment,['method'=>'PUT','route'=>['/enrollment',$enrollment->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!} not working for me Im getting Route [/enrollment] not defined.

Comment: got it now it's working thank you for your effort and answer.